# Show 2 condition on JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to show quote and new quote condition on diffrent div . Please help I want to show 2 condition, my code like this :

```
function setup() {
    output = document.getElementById("output2");
    var ws = new WebSocket('wss://www.binary.com/websockets/v3?l=RU');

    ws.onopen = function(evt) {
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({ticks:'R_50'}));
    }

    ws.onmessage = function(msg) {
        var quote = JSON.parse(msg.data).tick.quote;
        var newquote = quote.substr(-1);
        log(newquote);//here should be semi-colon
    } 

}

function log(info) {
    //Display information on screen
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = info;
    output.appendChild(p);
    console.log(info);
}

 function sendMessage(msg) {
    ws.send(msg);
    log("TICKS");
    ws.close();
}

window.addEventListener("load", setup, false);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please elaborate on the context and what you're trying to achieve, as currently it is somewhat unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create twi different `div` in `HTML`, and then do

**HTML**

```
<div id="quote-div"></div>
<div id="newquote-div"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Let id of div be an argument of function
function log(info, id) {
            var p = document.getElementById(id);
            p.innerHTML = info;
        }
// and use it like
var quote = JSON.parse(msg.data).tick.quote;
var newquote = quote.substr(-1);
log(quote, "quote-div");
log(newquote, "newquote-div");
```

Comment: Done... But if normal newquote with loop like this 2,3,4,5,6 and now just one digit and not loop, how to make normal result with loop

Comment: this is result :
before 
<img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/24wczza.png" width="100" height="100">

After 
<img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/taptlw.png" width="100" height="100">
for quote its ok, but how to make newquote like before i use your code . like an image ... thank you for your help :)